# Coverting SQL Queries into Hive Queries

Tags: mysql, hive

Can anyone please tell me how to convert the below SQL Query into Hive Query...

```
SELECT  GL_ACCT_ID ACCT_ID, gl_acct_nm as acct_nm,DA_REC_EFF_DT
FROM DSMT_GL_ACCT
WHERE setid ='FDL01'
AND ACCT_TYP_CD IN ('E')
AND DA_REC_EFF_DT>= TO_DATE(:P_ACTG_PRD_NO||'-'||:P_FYR,'MM-YYYY')
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you facing any specific error? Try running this in hive and post the error. Also provide your schema

Answer (score 0):

Try using '${P_ACTG_PRD_NO}' & '${P_FYR}'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  GL_ACCT_ID ACCT_ID, gl_acct_nm as acct_nm,DA_REC_EFF_DT
FROM DSMT_GL_ACCT
WHERE setid ='FDL01'
AND ACCT_TYP_CD IN ('E')
AND DA_REC_EFF_DT>=from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('${P_ACTG_PRD_NO}-${P_FYR}','MM-yyyy'),'MM-yyyy')
```